# Upload file CakePHP Fatal Error

Tags: php, cakephp, upload, cakephp-3.0

I try to upload a file on my cakephp app thanks to Josegonzalez/Upload. And I've got the following error.
In local everything works, but not in my server.
By the way, file upload with wordpress or with a simple PHP form works on my server.
I had to specify

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

to make it work for Wordpress in my php.ini. I also tried

```
open_basedir = /tmp
```

but it still does not work for cakephp.

`Fatal error: [InvalidArgumentException] Invalid stream reference provided #0 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/zendframework/zend-diactoros/src/Stream.php(58): Zend\Diactoros\Stream->setStream('/tmp/phpKu6O1j', 'r') #1 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/zendframework/zend-diactoros/src/UploadedFile.php(164): Zend\Diactoros\Stream->__construct('/tmp/phpKu6O1j') #2 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequest.php(460): Zend\Diactoros\UploadedFile->getStream() #3 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequest.php(361): Cake\Http\ServerRequest->_processFiles(Array, Array) #4 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequest.php(300): Cake\Http\ServerRequest->_setConfig(Array) #5 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequestFactory.php(56): Cake\Http\ServerRequest->__construct(Array) #6 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/c in /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/ErrorHandler.php on line 180`

Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/logs/error.log) is not within the allowed path(s): (..) in /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Engine/FileLog.php on line 188

Warning: file_put_contents(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/logs/error.log) is not within the allowed path(s): (..) in /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Engine/FileLog.php on line 133

Warning: file_put_contents(/home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/logs/error.log): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Log/Engine/FileLog.php on line 133

Fatal error: [InvalidArgumentException] Invalid stream reference provided #0 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/zendframework/zend-diactoros/src/Stream.php(58): Zend\Diactoros\Stream->setStream('/tmp/phpKu6O1j', 'r') #1 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/zendframework/zend-diactoros/src/UploadedFile.php(164): Zend\Diactoros\Stream->__construct('/tmp/phpKu6O1j') #2 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequest.php(460): Zend\Diactoros\UploadedFile->getStream() #3 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequest.php(361): Cake\Http\ServerRequest->_processFiles(Array, Array) #4 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequest.php(300): Cake\Http\ServerRequest->_setConfig(Array) #5 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ServerRequestFactory.php(56): Cake\Http\ServerRequest->__construct(Array) #6 /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/c in /home/rom1/public_html/cakephp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/ErrorHandler.php on line 180

Comment: Did you try to read the error message? Just google "open_basedir restriction in effect"

Comment: Of course I did ! Of course I googled it ! I've been working on this all the afternoon before writing on stackoverflow. As I told you, I tried to put open_basedir = /tmp in my php.ini file, I also tried to comment it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you restart Apache after updating your php.ini?

Comment: Yes I did restart apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood that the problem was not in my php.ini.

As I’m working with userdir, I had to go to /etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf

And change

```
php_admin_value open_basedir ".."
```

To

```
php_admin_value open_basedir ..:/tmp
```

But I can’t get why it was working with Wordpress and not CakePHP…